# Concatenate Strings in Arguments

Tags: r

I have a trouble to calculate multiple similar tasks in a loop. I try to manipulate arguments with simple for loops but I fail each time.

The example I share here is from a survival analysis but I seek a solution for all similar tasks.

I made prior calculations with `surv_cutpoint()` and for the step calculating fit value with `survfit()` I wrote a for loop since I want to calculate overall survival(OS) and disease-free survival(DFS) for each 2 protein levels separately.

I am sorry if my question is too basic but I could not find the answer.

The loop is this

```
for (i in c("protein1", "protein2")){
  for(f in c("OS", "DFS")){
    column_name<- paste0(i,"_IHC_Score")
    fit_name<-paste0(f,"_fit_",i)
    time <- paste0(f,"_month")
    status <- paste0(f,"_status")
    data_name <- paste0("dummy_", f)
    paste(fit_name)<- survfit(
      formula = Surv(time, status) ~ column_name,
      data = data_name)
  }
}
```

I receive the error
`Time variable is not numeric`
I thought the issue is quotes but `noquote()` did not help.

As an example, the formula supposed the work like this for "protein 1" and "Overall survival":

```
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(OS_month, OS_status) ~ protein1_IHC_Score, 
    data = dummy_OS)

   27 observations deleted due to missingness 
                         n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
protein1_IHC_Score=high 41      7     NA      32      NA
protein1_IHC_Score=low  56      5     NA      NA      NA
```

and the result:

The datasets are like this

```
> head(dummy_OS)
   OS_month    OS_status    protein1_IHC_Score     protein2_IHC_Score
1      104         0                low               high
2       91         0               high               high
3       49         0                low               high
4      111         0                low               <NA>
5      105         0                low               high
6       52         0               high               high
> head(dummy_DFS)
    DFS_month   DFS_status   protein1_IHC_Score   protein2_IHC_Score
1       104          0                low               high
2        91          0               high               high
3        49          0                low               high
4       111          0                low               <NA>
5       105          0                low               high
6        52          0               high               high
```

Comment: What's the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the last code

```
paste(fit_name) <- survfit(
  formula = Surv(time, status) ~ column_name,
  data = data_name
)
```

to

```
assign(fit_name, survfit(
  formula = as.formula(paste0("Surv(", time, ", ", status, ") ~ ", column_name)),
  data = eval(parse(text=data_name))
))
```

For further improvement, I would recommend not to save each result to distinct variable but to save them into a single list together.
For example,

```
map(c(protein1="protein1", protein2="protein2"), function(i){
  imap(c(OS=dummy_OS, DFS=dummy_DFS), function(data_name, f){
    survfit(
      formula = as.formula(paste0(
        "Surv(", f, "_month", ", ", f, "_status", ") ~ ", f, "_status"
      )),
      data = data_name
    )
  })
})
```

would produce a nested list such as

```
$protein1
$protein1$OS
survfit object 1

$protein1$DFS
survfit object 2


$protein2
$protein2$OS
survfit object 3

$protein2$DFS
survfit object 4
```

I hope this would help!